# Bluetooth turns off after reboot

Tags: bluetooth

After rebooting, I need to manually turn on bluetooth and click to connect my mouse.  Is there a way to tell Loki to remember from last time that bluetooth was on and to reconnect the mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terminal:

Enter the `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` file.
There you'll find settings for bluetooth.
I see that the last line is about AutoEnable, change it to true.

:)

Comment: Thanks @Dysproz, this forces bluetooth to be on.  Is there a way to force it to reconnect to the bluetooth mouse after rebooting?  I still need to manually select the mouse using the touchpad.

Comment: I found that: 1. Turn on your mouse 2.In terminal use hcitool scan 3.You'll see your mouse and it's MAC address. 4. Paste <device oui="You Mouse MAC address" type="mouse" name="Your mouse name" pin="0000"/> to /usr/share/gnome-bluetooth/pin-code-database.xml . I'm not sure if that'll work, but I saw that here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486347/bluetooth-mouse-not-auto-reconnecting-to-laptop/582035#582035

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried your suggestion plus others in the link without success.  What's odd is that the mouse will work for about a second, then go to sleep until I select it from the bluetooth widget (using my touchpad).  Also, the mouse is shown twice in the widget.  Bluetooth is the most quirky feature I've experienced using Linux.